# Gerar links e baixar conteúdo programaticamente

Tags: r, web-scraping

Gostaria de saber como eu faria para coletar dados dados de um website.

O site é http://www.ons.org.br/historico/energia_natural_afluente.aspx . Lá eu tenho que baixar todos os dados do históricos de operação desde geração de energia até Energia Natural Afluente. O problema é que dentro de cada série de dados, você é direcionado para uma página para fazer a seleção do subsistema (SE/CO, S, NE e N), unidade, ano, etc. E quando as opções são selecionadas, o link da página não é alterado então não se pode discriminar para fazer o scan automaticamente.

Eu desejo fazer um banco de dados com todas essas informações. Como eu uso bastante o R, gostaria de saber um código de R para tal.

Comment: Se for apenas baixar e se a navegabilidade for simples, você pode usar o seleniumhq, essa ferramenta automatiza operações com navegador, talvez possa ajuda-lo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você consegue fazer isso usando o pacote `rvest`. O código a seguir vai te ajudar:

```
library(rvest)
# criando a sessão de navegação
sessao <- html_session("http://www.ons.org.br/historico/energia_natural_afluente.aspx")
# identificando o formulário que deseja "POSTAR"
form <- sessao %>% html_form()
form <- form[[4]]
# atribuindo os valores aos parâmetros do formulário
values <- set_values(form = form,
                     passo1="SE",
                     passo2a="-1",
                     passo2b="MWmed",
                     passo3a="-1",
                     passo3b="2015",
                     tipo="regiao",
                     passo2="MWmed",
                     passo3="2015",
                     passo4="-1",
                     passo1text="SE",
                     passo2text="MWmed",
                     passo3text="2015",
                     passo4text="-1"
                     )
# submetendo o formulário
resposta <- submit_form(sessao, values)
# obtendo as tabelas da resposta do formulário
tabelas <- resposta %>% html_table(fill = T, header = T)
# identificando a tabela desejada
tabela <- tabelas[[2]]
```

No objeto `tabela` você vai encontrar provavelmente os valores que você está procurando:

```
> tabela
        2015
1  Jan 21466
2  Fev 34907
3  Mar 43126
4  Abr 37029
5  Mai 30293
6  Jun 23248
7  Jul 28362
8  Ago 16195
9  Set 21010
10 Out 19459
11 Nov 32269
```

Agora você precisa apenas mapear as opções que você deseja obter os dados e passá-las por meio da função `set_values`.

Comment: Perfeito. Muito obrigado. Não sei lidar com html ainda, mas vou estudar o pacote.

Comment: Quando se usa a função submit_form, o x no caso que você usou seria o quê? Quando eu rodo o código que você postos ele apresenta uns erros, pois o x não definido.

Comment: ops, é o `sessao`. Vou editar na resposta

Comment: Só uma coisa Daniel Falbel, dentro de `set_values` tá o mapeamento com padrão `id_objeto_html=valor_desejado`, é isso?

Comment: @GustavoCinque, não tenho certeza se é o `id` ou o `name`. O que eu fiz foi ver pelo navegador qual é  `header` de quando envio o formulário p/ o servidor. No Chrome, deixo a janela de desenvolvedor aberta (F12) e envio o formulário. Em seguida na aba `Network`, vejo qual foi o `form data` do primeiro arquivo recebido `energia_natural_afluente_out.aspx`.

Comment: Entendi. Realmente é uma solução bem legal. Bem menos complicado de trabalhar do que Webservice em Java.

Comment: Sim! Acho que `R` e `python` estão se desenvolvendo bastante nesse lado de tornar webscrapping fácil. O `rvest` que usei aqui é inspirado no famoso `beautiful soup` do `python`.

Comment: @Daniel Falbel Tentei rodar exatamente o código que você colocou acima, mas não obtive sucesso. A tabela final aparece vazia com zero linhas. 
`> tabela
[1]              Fale Conosco              Mapa do Site              Links Úteis 
<0 linhas> (ou row.names de comprimento 0)`
Tentei mudar os passos etc., mas tive sucesso.

Comment: @BrunoMoreno muito estranho, acabei de rodar de novo e obtive o mesmo resultado. Não teve nenhum erro no meio?

Comment: @Daniel Falbel não to entendendo nada. Eu uso o R Studio, mas tenho R no meu computador também. Quando rodo no R studio ele dá o erro que eu disse, mas quando rodo no R puro ele não dá erro. Sabe o que pode ser?